# Error :No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/test'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a webapi project with a base ApiController named TestController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using TestDataAcess;

namespace Test2.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<table> Get()
        {
            using (Test_Raw_DataEntities entities = new Test_Raw_DataEntities())
            {
                return entities.table.ToList();
            }
        }
        public table Get(int ID)
            {
            using (Test_Raw_DataEntities entities = new Test_Raw_DataEntities())
                {
                    return entities.table.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id==ID);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to go to the URL, it generates the following message:

Error :

> No type was found that matches the controller named 'table' and no
>   HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost/api/test'

Comment: The url `http://localhost/api/table` should be `http://localhost/api/test`

Comment: Do you host your application on port 80?